# Can I configure Google Analytics to use the canonical URL?

Tags: google-analytics, canonical-url, rel-canonical

The website includes pages like

- `example.com/category1/product1` and
- `example.com/category2/product1` and
- `example.com/category3/product1`

Here, the `example.com/category1/product1` is the canonical page; and all other pages are duplicate pages.

The duplicate pages are marked with proper canonical tags using `<link rel="canonical" href="example.com/category1/product1"/>`

Although, all of these duplicate pages contain the same Google Analytics Code. So are these three pages considered as individual pages in Google Analytics? If yes, then how to configure Google Analytics so that traffic to the all three URLs are consolidated in one single canonical URL?

Comment: How do you set up your Analytics tracking: ga.js, gtag.js, Google Tag Manager or any other methods?

Comment: I am going to use global site tag (gtag.js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify your Google Analytics tracking snippet to use the canonical URL that you specify.  Your normal GA tracking snippet should look something like [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/):

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');    
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

[Google has instructions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages) for modifying the `ga('send', 'pageview');` line to specify the URL of the page getting tracked.  Their example is `ga('send', 'pageview', location.pathname);`

This [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980682/obtaining-canonical-url-using-javascript) has the JavaScript to get the canonical URL:  `document.querySelector("link[rel='canonical']").getAttribute("href");`

We can put that together to use the `location.pathname` unless the `canonical` exists.  We can also use the regular expression `/https?:\/\/[^\/]+/i` to strip the protocol and host name off the canonical URL.

```
var path=location.pathname
var canonical=document.querySelector("link[rel='canonical']")
if (canonical) path=canonical.getAttribute('href').replace(/https?:\/\/[^\/]+/i,'')
ga('send', 'pageview', path);
```

The only other wrinkle is that your canonical needs to be defined **before** your GA snippet.   Otherwise it won't be in the page when the JS looks for it.  your final canonical and snippet should look something like this in the `<head>` section of your pages:

```
<link rel=canonical href="http://example.com/hello-world">
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');    
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
var path=location.pathname
var canonical=document.querySelector("link[rel='canonical']")
if (canonical) path=canonical.getAttribute('href').replace(/https?:\/\/[^\/]+/i,'')
ga('send', 'pageview', path);
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

This doesn't check to make sure the canonical is on another page on your own site.   If you use some external canonical URLs to other sites, you would have to add some more checks to the code.